# Unwanted Dot in Checkboxs

Tags: html, css, checkbox, frontend, styling

I am having issues with an unwanted dot appearing in my checkboxes due to my CSS styling. I am unsure how to remove it or what is causing it.

Here is a link to the site it is on: 
[JavaJam Coffee House](http://webpages.uncc.edu/~akenne36/Labs/Lab5/Kennedy1Yanzu2-Lab5.html#)

The form below the Newsletter header is the only section of the site pertaining to the question. Notice the small dot in the top left corner of the checkboxes.

Any tips or insight on this issue would be very appreciated.

HTML Code pertaining to question:

```html
<input type=checkbox name="coupon" id="coupon">
<label for="coupon" class="check"><span>Include coupons</span></label>
<br><br>
<input type=checkbox name="magazine" id="magazine">
<label for="magazine" class="check"><span>Include magazines</span></label>
<br><br>
<input type=checkbox name="certificates" id="certificates">
<label for="certificates" class="check"><span>Include gift certificates</span></label>
<br><br>    
<input type="submit" value="Register">
<br><br>
```

CSS Code pertaining to question:

```css
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  clip: rect(0 0 1 1);
}

input[type=checkbox] + label::before {
  content: "\00a0"; /* non-line breaking space */
  display: inline-block; 
  width:12px;
  height: 12px;  
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em; 
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 0.125em solid #680000; 
  background-color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before { 
  content: "\2713"; /*checkmark */ 
  color: #680000; 
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: REFER TO THIS URL BELOW ----- 

http://webpages.uncc.edu/~akenne36/Labs/Lab5/Kennedy1Yanzu2-Lab5.html#

 -------Had to change the file path.

Comment: This may sound dumb but try reseting your browser zoom. I cannot see your issue unless I hit 90% zoom, then there is a small dot in the checkbox. Most browsers zoom can be fix with `ctrl + 0`

Comment: i don't see a dot, using chrome. can you provide screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

try editing this style

```
    input[type=checkbox] {
      position: absolute;
      /* height: 1px; */
      /* width: 1px; */
      left: -2000px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      clip: rect(0 0 1 1);
    }
```

I commented the width and height as they are the reason the dot appears in the first place and added a left property to send the input off screen

Comment: Or you can set `visibility: hidden;` - I used the inspector (right-click, inspect; or hit F12) to experiment with fixes.